# Windows 2008 schtasks and Task Scheduler Library folders

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have an old scripts which kicks off a scheduled task:

`schtasks /end /tn MyTaskName /s HOSTNAME`

I am now trying to use it on Windows 2008, but it doesn't work.
I think it's to do with the fact that the new Task Scheduler allows you to specify subfolders under the main "Task Scheduler Library" and I have put MyTaskName in a subfolder called MyTasks.
What's the correct syntax to use with schtasks?

Answer (score 0):

Does the local version work?

e.g. schtasks /end /tn "MyTaskName"

If so, it may be a firewalling issue.